# Count Number of Occurrences of a Text in a PowerBI Column

Tags: powerbi

I have a column where I'm trying to the specific occurrences of a substring. Here is how the column goes:

FaN,,,
CC-22, CC-23, CC-24, FaN
CC-23, CC-24
CC-22, CC-23, CC-24, FaN

I tried to use a combination of Filter and Containsstring but received an error message. I have also tried. I also created a new table but the results are too rigid for to use with the fields that were there initially.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are those repeating values inside your column? Why not split them out to a separate table?

Answer (score 0):

Your **Measure** could look like:

```
Column Count =
  CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS('YourTable'),
    CONTAINSSTRING('YourTable'[your column], "CC-23")
  )
```

Comment: Hello,
I was able to get it to work by creating an 'All' variable. Thank you for your help.